# ubuntu karmic default application

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I'm new here and new to Ubuntu too.

I want to set default  application for sql and text files for opening with gedit.

I've already try 'Open with' with no success. I've also checked '/etc/gnome/defaults.list' and found this line 'text/x-sql=gedit.desktop'and I'm new but it seems fine. Don't know why I get this when I try to open mentioned files:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Nautilus` (the default ubuntu file browser) then go to `edit->preferences` and to the `behaviour` tab. Then check the option:

```
view executables text files...
```

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the files that you want to change the default application for (your sql and text files) and click **Properties**:

[image]

Navigate to the **Open With** tab and you can change the default application with the radio button:

[image]

Comment: don't want to be impolite but I posted "I've already try 'Open with' with no success"

Comment: The open with from the context menu is not the same as the one in properties, which one have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that because the file is marked as executable.  The file manager is just saying "*hey! do you want me to* **run this as a program**, *or* **open it as a text file**?"

Does it open in GEdit properly if you click "Display"?  If so, your file associations are set correctly.  You can then get rid of this extra dialog with one of the following:

- Follow [mrucci's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/76275/ubuntu-karmic-default-application/76439#76439) to tell Nautilus to just display executable text files instead of offering to run them.  OR...
- Remove the executable permission from the file if it doesn't need it.  Run `chmod -x myfile.sql` on the file to remove the executable bit.  Then Nautilus won't offer to run it.

The second option is not doable with `chmod` on FAT32 or NTFS filesystems.  You'd have to mount the drives with certain mount options (eg `-o noexec`) to get the same effect.

**Edit**: There is a third option.  Instead of double-clicking to auto-open the files, get into the habit of right-clicking and choosing the "Edit" option.  This is what I do on Windows with `.bat` files, and in Thunar on Xubuntu with shellscripts (`.sh`) -- I don't know offhand but I'd expect the default file manager in Ubuntu can do this too.  It's a good habit to get into -- even if I tweak my computer to behave "properly", someone else's system won't behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus -> Edit -> Preferences

[image]